# How to better the display of an iterated array result in php

Tags: php

I have an array response from an api and i want to display it nicely, but doesnt work.

here is the code

```
function test($firstDate, $secondDate, $dayOfWeek) {
    file_get_contents('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/stocks');
    $theResponse = file_get_contents('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/stocks/?page=1');
    $response = json_decode($theResponse);
    foreach($response->data as $Key=>$data){
       $data = (array)$data;
        $arrObject = new ArrayObject($data);
        $arrayIterator = $arrObject->getIterator();

        while( $arrayIterator->valid() )
        {
            echo $arrayIterator->current() . "%s ";
            $arrayIterator->next();
        }
    }
      
}
```

now here is the response it gave

```
5-January-2000%s 5265.09%s 5464.35%s 5184.48%s 5357%s 6-January-2000%s 5424.21%s 5489.86%s 5391.33%s 5421.53%s 7-January-2000%s 5358.28%s 5463.25%s 5330.58%s 5414.48%s 11-January-2000%s 5513.04%s 5537.69%s 5221.28%s 5296.3%s 13-January-2000%s 5568.64%s 5652.22%s 5430.81%s 5444.82%s 14-January-2000%s 5460.31%s 5476.38%s 5344.59%s 5471.27%s 17-January-2000%s 5617.7%s 5664.5%s 5404.07%s 5404.07%s 21-January-2000%s 5352.63%s 5441.83%s 5330.08%s 5423.05%s 27-January-2000%s 5424.14%s 5457.3%s 5362.25%s 5369.1%s 28-January-2000%s 5417.53%s 5417.53%s 5331.54%s 5335.8%s 31-January-2000%s 5338.67%s 5345.3%s 5186.32%s 5205.29%s 1-February-2000%s 5217.65%s 5232.84%s 5127.79%s 5215.54%s 2-February-2000%s 5264.62%s 5342.98%s 5264.62%s 5304.92%s 3-February-2000%s 5366.62%s 5381.74%s 5323.32%s 5340.19%s 7-February-2000%s 5431.55%s 5518.29%s 5431.55%s 5474%s 8-February-2000%s 5585.38%s 5647.64%s 5585.38%s 5610.56%s 9-February-2000%s 5704.01%s 5756.87%s 5635.69%s 5649.1%s 11-February-2000%s 5985.05%s 6005.85%s 5917.04%s 5933.56{-truncated-}
```

but I want it to display like this format

```
17-January-2000 5617.7 5404.07
31-January-2000 5338.67 5205.29
7-February-2000 5431.55 5474
14-February-2000 6130.23 5924.31
21-February-2000 5874.25 5876.89
```

Comment: So, the difference is the `%s` that you've explicitly put in your code?

Comment: I'm also unsure why you're doing all this stuff with ArrayObject / getIterator or converting $data, which should already be an array, to an array? Wouldn't a `foreach` do?

Comment: when i did for each, it gave me an array which i am now using while loop to iterate thru

Comment: the original response i got is an stdclass object

Comment: If you use `json_decode($what, true)` it will return an array instead.